# Why org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component

Tags: tomcat, struts2

Tomcat can't start out of blue or I don't remember where I changed. The error messages are as below.

```
SEVERE: A child container failed during start
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[]]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:188)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1123)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:799)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)

Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.servlet.ServletContext.getClassLoader()Ljava/lang/ClassLoader;
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.WebappServiceLoader.load(WebappServiceLoader.java:90)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processServletContainerInitializers(ContextConfig.java:1543)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.webConfig(ContextConfig.java:1265)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfig.java:873)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:371)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:117)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5355)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
```

Why `org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException`: Failed to start component ?

Comment: Check that you have not duplicate servlet-api jars when deployed to the tomcat server.

Comment: it was solved earlier. but i am not so sure where the problems were. i think you are probably right. the problems were about the jar files. like:

put these only in tomcat/lib
servlet-api.jar
geronimo-servlet_2.5_spec.jar

put struts2 jars only in WEB-INF/lib

add commons-logging.jar and servlet-api.jar in server's classpath...

Comment: Can you run the server after a fresh installation?

Comment: yes, it can start properly. just another problem during runtime, about notfoundcexception. i posted it here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23220862/classnotfoundexception-strutsprepareandexecutefilter-in-struts2

Comment: You have wrong versions of libraries, messed up with the server jars. Try maven, download only required jars from the central repository, and you are almost done.

Comment: @RomanC, how can i know the versions are wrong? my network doesnt allow me to download with maven and i tried before. and im not using maven.   u mean the servlet-api.jar ?

Comment: @user3560221 i'm also working on a struts2 project. even i didn't used maven. what i did was to download latest jars from maven repo. here's the link for [struts2 core](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.struts/struts2-core) you can search for other jars here only. you can also download complete struts package from apache website. its hardly 13-14mb

Answer (score 0):

You have wrong versions of libraries, messed up with the server jars. Try maven, download only required jars from the central repository, and you are almost done. See the example of developing a maven project  [Create Struts 2 Web Application Using Maven To Manage Artifacts and To Build The Application](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/plugins/servlet/mobile?contentId=14811868#content/view/14811868).

You can start comparing them from the lib folder and the struts lib package. `servlet-api` only needs to compile your app but should *not* deploy it.

Comment: aren't the servlet API's are provided by the container?

Comment: yes, they are provided, and *should not deploy it*, but they are might not be available during a compile time.