# HTTP 404 Error in struts example project on Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, apache, tomcat, jakarta-ee, struts2

I want to run some of code from https://github.com/apache/struts-examples with eclipse. I get a 404 error when I import and run. But I haven't changed any lines and I'm not getting errors
I have already done Tomcat and Run Configrations

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QVTzc.png)

https://github.com/apache/struts-examples/tree/master/file-upload

Comment: Please see the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23222976/573032