# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter at building normal struts login application

Tags: java, maven, struts2, struts

Facing this issue while building a simple Struts application

All the jar files are correctly imported as my another struts application is working perfectly

Web.xml

```
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:jsp="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/jsp"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">

    <display-name>WB AOS Data Admin App</display-name>

    <filter>
    <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter</filter-class>
  </filter>
  <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </filter-mapping>
```

Comment: No....already tried everything mentioned there

Comment: How do you build the application? check the WEB-INF/lib where the required jar is there.

Comment: What version of Struts 2? That's an older filter.

Comment: @DaveNewton I checked the class , it is present with the same address

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sometimes additional imported dependencies can cause this type of error. Try reducing to the minimum required dependencies for a Struts 2 application.

[See the linked question/answer for more help regarding this error.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23220862/classnotfoundexception-strutsprepareandexecutefilter-in-struts2)

Additional information:

[How To Create A Struts 2 Web Application](https://struts.apache.org/getting-started/how-to-create-a-struts2-web-application.html)

Comment: Thanks for help..some of my dependencies were imported twice and that was causing these error